# Using variables in property names in LESS (dynamic properties / property name interpolation)

Tags: css, less, vendor-prefix

I noticed that inuit.css, which was written in SASS, has a .vendor mix-in:

```
@mixin vendor($property, $value...){
    -webkit-#{$property}:$value;
       -moz-#{$property}:$value;
        -ms-#{$property}:$value;
         -o-#{$property}:$value;
            #{$property}:$value;
}
```

Is there a way to replicate this in LESS with some of the odd features like e() and @{ } ?

Answer (score 59):

### Update: LESS >= 1.6

As of version 1.6 (see **[changelog](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**) property name interpolation is implemented in LESS. So you don't need any magic anymore. (For older versions, see my original answer.)

Your mixin would work basically as is:

LESS:

```
.vendor(@property; @value){
    -webkit-@{property}: @value;
       -moz-@{property}: @value;
        -ms-@{property}: @value;
         -o-@{property}: @value;
            @{property}: @value;
}

/*example*/
.test {
    .vendor(transform, translateX(20px));
}
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
  -o-transform: translateX(20px);
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

---

### Original answer: LESS < 1.6

As far as I'm concerned less hasn't added support for dynamically inserted properties, which has been previously discussed on SO many times, see maybe:

- [LESS CSS Escape entire CSS rule with different prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920935/less-css-escape-entire-css-rule-with-different-prefixes/14943680#14943680)
- [Generic `vendors` mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084150/generic-vendors-mixin)
- [Rounded corner tables with LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530267/rounded-corner-tables-with-less)

So the way it is usually done would be with parametric mixins and pattern matching ... so it is a little bit more hard coding ... but properties and different vendors anyway sometimes require a little different format of parameters, so a little more control is added this way.

### Workaround #1:  inject dynamicaly generated properties into a properties value

The first option for a workaround is a bit ugly but I tried it and it worked on [http://less2css.org](http://less2css.org/).
So, what I tried was to inject the dynamically created properties into a value of another property that you hard code (which I just gave a random "vendor" name `-inj` here and assigned it value `ect`, but you might want to use something usefull instead if you already add an element in from of all vendor mixin includes)

```
.vendors(@property, @value, @pre: ect) {
    -inj:~"@{pre}; -webkit-@{property}: @{value}; -moz-@{property}: @{value}; -ms-@{property}: @{value}; -o-@{property}: @{value}; @{property}: @{value}";
}
```

We can try it on an example - maybe something to make it worth ... lets try transform short:

**LESS:**

```
.test-class{
    .vendors(transform, matrix(1,0,0,1,20,20));
    .vendors(transform-origin,"10px 10px");
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
.test-class {
    -inj: ect; -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20); -moz-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20); -ms-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20); -o-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20); transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20);
    -inj: ect; -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 10px; -moz-transform-origin: 10px 10px; -ms-transform-origin: 10px 10px; -o-transform-origin: 10px 10px; transform-origin: 10px 10px;
}
```

This seems to produce working css but it feels kinnda wrong =)

---

### Workaround #2:  inject dynamicaly generated properties into the name of the folowing class (up to v1.3.3)

So I played with this idea a little more ... and thought of a way that does not produce unnecessary properties. It injects the dynamically created properties into the name of the next class. Let me show you how I got it to work:

**1)** Let us define a general vendor mixin (the `@rest` argument will be used to line up multiple vendor blocks later)

```
.vendors(@property, @value, @rest:"") {
    @inject:~"@{rest} -webkit-@{property}: @{value}; -moz-@{property}: @{value}; -ms-@{property}: @{value}; -o-@{property}: @{value}; @{property}: @{value};";
}
```

**2)** Construct a virtual class/ruleset that we want the vendors to be included in, but we make it as a mixin that at the end constructs the next class aswel - so we really make a mixin that will recursively build two or more classes. For example (using the same example as above) we can write something like this (notice the use of `@inject` in the second `.vendor()` call to bind the two vendor blocks together):

```
.test(@nextclass){
    .vendors(transform, "matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20)");
    .vendors(transform-origin,"10px 10px", @inject);
    (~"{@{inject}} .@{nextclass}"){/*next class properties*/};
}
```

**3)** Now just we wrap this mixin into another class to display in the css:

```
.this-class{
    .test(next-class);
}
```

The resulting **CSS** will include this:

```
.this-class {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -moz-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -ms-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -o-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -o-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  transform-origin: 10px 10px;
}
.next-class {
  /*next class properties*/
}
```

The output will be just all in one line.

**Edit:** For nicer formatting you can include javascript interpolation of `"\n"` and `"\t"`, see Scott's suggestion in comments below.

This way you can now chain up multiple classes all using the vendor mixin, without any unnecessary properties.

---

### Workaround #3:  inject dynamicaly generated properties into the name of the folowing class (v1.4.0) using recursion

I am adding this cause Scott pointed out in one of the comments that the changes that are coming with version 1.4 won't allow the workaround #2. But if we are a little resourceful, we can overcome this this problem. Let us see what are the problems of above workaround and fix them.

**1) The first problem** would be that the "`(~".@{index}") { ...` selector interpolation is deprecated", so we need to do the string interpolation in a separate step. Implementing this would be enough to inject a single `.vendors` mixin from above.

**LESS:** (using Scott's newline suggestion):

```
@nl: `"\n\t"`;        
.vendors(@property, @value) {
    @inject:~"@{nl}-webkit-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-moz-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-ms-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-o-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}@{property}: @{value};";
}
.test(@nextclass){
    .vendors(transform, "matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20)");
    @inj: ~"{@{inject}`'\n'`} `'\n'`.@{nextclass}";
    @{inj} {/*next class properties*/}
}
.this-class{
    .test(next-class);
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
.this-class {
    -webkit-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20);
    -moz-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20);
    -ms-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20);
    -o-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20);
    transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20);
} 
.next-class {
    /*next class properties*/
}
```

**2) The second problem** would be that "variables in mixins no longer 'leak' into their calling scope", but I noticed in the 1.4.0 beta, that if a variable is only introduced in a mixin it still can be called from the including ruleset, so with a little recursion, you could construct the `.vendors` blocks, and in the last step assign them to a new variable, that you then use for injection. I also got excited and used the new `extract()` function introduced in this version of less. With variable `@i` we assign the level of recursion (number of vendor blocks to be injected).

**LESS:**

```
@nl: `"\n\t"`; 
.multi(@props,@vals,1,@inj) {
    @property: extract(@props, 1);
    @value: extract(@vals, 1);
    @inject:~"@{inj}@{nl}-webkit-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-moz-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-ms-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-o-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}@{property}: @{value};";
}

.multi(@props,@vals,@i,@inj:"") when (@i > 0) {
    @property: extract(@props, @i);
    @value: extract(@vals, @i);
    @injnext:~"@{inj}@{nl}-webkit-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-moz-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-ms-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}-o-@{property}: @{value};@{nl}@{property}: @{value};";
    .multi(@props,@vals,(@i - 1),@injnext);
}

@properties: "transform-origin" "transform";
@values: "10px 10px" "matrix(2,0,0,2,20,20)";

// string of other properties you want to include in the same class
@p: ~"@{nl}width:20px; @{nl}height:12px; @{nl}background-color:#000;";

.this-class {
    .multi(@properties,@values,2,@p);
    @inj: ~"{@{inject}`'\n'`} `'\n'`.next-class ";
    @{inj} {/**/}
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
.this-class {
  width:20px;
  height:12px;
  background-color:#000;
  -webkit-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -moz-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -ms-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -o-transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 20, 20);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  -o-transform-origin: 10px 10px;
  transform-origin: 10px 10px;
}
.next-class {
  /*next class properties*/
}
```

Now this worked pretty well for me in 1.4.0 beta, but let us see what the future brings.

Comment: +1 for a creative workaround. I hope [they resolve this](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1199) sometime soon so such workarounds are not needed. Note that if you put a variable definition into `.test` mixin like this `@newline: \`"\n"\`` (note the `\n` string is javascript processed), then you can put `@{newline}` every place in your string code you actually want a newline character to show up, which will format your code to not be a single line only.

Comment: I just noticed that LESS 1.4 is not going to allow this workaround (and a number of other things I have done to answer some issues) because of this: [`variables in mixins no longer 'leak' into their calling scope`](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Ok, I looked into the problems and came up with another workaround, that works in 1.4.0 beta ... this game is kinda fun, but I think my answer already turned into a novel, so I will retire =)

Comment: Thanks for another workable solution for 1.4. I noticed a quirk if you add a normal property to the `.this-class` it separates it out under a second `.this-class` definition. Unfortunate, but not critical.

Comment: Seems so, couse we are actually making a subclass of `.this-class` by the injection. I guess if you dont want it to be split up, you need to inject it together with the rest ... through string interpolation - something like this `@p: "@{nl}width:20px; @{nl}height:12px; @{nl}background-color:#fff;" ` and passing it to the `@inj` argument of the `.muli` mixin, or  I guess you could modify the `multi` mixing itself so that it adds any dynamic properties not only vendor ones. I added the @p into the last example above, to show the result.

Comment: Yes, what you did was similar to what I did to get around it in testing also.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add that you can use 'minus' as a propery name and the parser will ignore it but add the rest of the string. That way you won't get an empty `inject:;` or inj propery.
It's still hacky but hey... :)

```
.prefix(@property, @value) {
    -:~";-webkit-@{property}: @{value}; -moz-@{property}: @{value}; -ms-@{property}: @{value}; -o-@{property}: @{value}; @{property}: @{value}";
}
```

**Example:**

```
.prefix(transition, "all .2s, color 0s");
```

**Will output:**

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s, color 0;
-moz-transition: all .2s, color 0;
-ms-transition: all .2s, color 0;
-o-transition: all .2s, color 0;
transition: all .2s, color 0;
```