# @viewport, @media and LESS

Tags: css, less, media-queries, viewport

I've recently converted some CSS to LESS for use with a .NET application (I am using dotless for .NET, http://www.dotlesscss.org/ to compile the LESS at runtime).

The compiler is falling down on these two blocks of code:

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
}
/* Add a min-width for IE 8 and lower */
@media \0screen\,screen\9 {
    body {
        min-width: 960px;
    }
}
```

Just for your reference, the media query above is a hacky way of targeting IE

How can I "LESS-ify" these blocks of code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Less >= 1.4.0 you can simply define a variable and use it in the media query:

```
@iehack: \0screen\,screen\9;

@media @iehack {
    body {
        min-width: 960px;
    }
}
```

In older versions of LESS (<=1.3.3) you might want to use string string interpolation in the variable:

```
@iehack: ~'\0screen\,screen\9';
```

This should give you your desired output.

But if you want to go a hacky way in CSS you can as well go a hacky way in LESS too:

```
@themedia: ~"@media \0screen\,screen\9 {";
@aftermedia: ~"} after";
@{themedia} {
    body {
        min-width: 960px;
    }
}
@{aftermedia}{/*just to add the closing bracket to media*/}
```

where you inject the media query around a normal role, this generates an extra selector at the end of the media block, but you can use it for something useful as well, this technique might be used in [**more exciting instances**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042/using-an-argument-for-tag-name-in-less/15443008#15443008) than media queries ... but I just wanted to mention it.

In this case the CSS output would look like:

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 { 
body {
  min-width: 960px;
}
}
after {
  /*just to add the closing bracket to media*/
}
```