# Less Mixin Variable within CSS selector

Tags: less

Is is possible to concatonate the value of a less mixin variable within a css selector name?

ie:

```
.leftImage{
    .alignContent(left);
}

.alignContent(@side: left; @marAmount: 20px;){
    img{
        float: @side
        margin-@side: @marAmount;
    } 
}
```

So what im trying to do is mixin the value of @side (in this instance) with a partial css selector of 'margin-' ultimately trying to create 'margin-'left'' (without the quotes)

Answer (score 2):

In LESS 1.6.x and higher it is [as simple as](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties):

```css
.leftImage {
    .alignContent(left);
}

.alignContent(@side: left, @marAmount: 20px) {
    img {
        float: @side;
        margin-@{side}: @marAmount;
    } 
}
```

But same is possible with earlier versions too, just needs some gentle hacks: [Using variables in property names in LESS (dynamic properties / property name interpolation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042) etc.