# Tell LESS to not freak out in certain special cases and ignore weird characters

Tags: css, less

Our server has a custom language-switcher for our CSS files. It recognizes certain patterns and switches `left` & `right` commands (among other things). To tell it where to switch, we use `@RIGHT@` and `@LEFT@` wherever needed:

```
div.somecls {
    margin-@RIGHT@: 15px;

    &:after {
        content: "\f061";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        @LEFT@: 10px;
        top: 20px;
    }
}
```

This also extends to class names themselves:

```
.push-@RIGHT@ {
    /* ... */
}
```

Till now, I wrote a node-script that compiled the css then replaced `left` and `right` with the proper replacements. However, I'm wondering - **is there's a way to tell LESS to just ignore some things and regard them as normal?**

That way I could write `@LEFT@` in the LESS file itself instead of overthinking it all (this would allow a lot of flexibility, especially if there are cases where I *don't* want the language switcher to do anything and rather use `left`)

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/hgofF) what you want? You can do it using escaped strings.

Comment: @Harry holy crap, YES!

Comment: @Harry I'd love an explanation how this witchcraft happens (i.e. what that magical tilda is doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell LESS to ignore characters like `@` by using escaped strings like below:

It is basically like doing `var a = "1+2";` in any programming language. It treats it as a string and doesn't perform any extra operations. But in LESS when we just provide `"@RIGHT@"`, it gets printed with the quotes, to avoid the quotes we need to use the tilda character in front.

```
@right: ~"@RIGHT@";
@left: ~"@LEFT@";

div.somecls {
    margin-@{right}: 15px;

    &:after {
        content: "\f061";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        border-@{left}: 10px;
        top: 20px;
    }
}
div.@{left}{
  color: blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/hgofF)

---

**Update:**

As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927419/tell-less-to-not-freak-out-in-certain-special-cases-and-ignore-weird-characters/24928303?noredirect=1#comment38736301_24928303), earlier the above method would not work when the property-value pair is like `@{left}: 10px`. That is, when compiled it would not produce output as `@LEFT@: 10px`. This issue has now been [**fixed**](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2173).

Comment: @yuvi: One small thing note, using the above method the `@{left}: 10px` alone would not produce `@LEFT@: 10px` output. Seems like it is a limitation. But we can overcome it by doing a workaround as `-inj:~"1; @{left}:"10px;`. This would produce `-inj: 1; @LEFT@: 10px;` but the `-inj: 1;` has no meaning and hence all browsers would just ignore it. Approach is picked from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042/using-variables-in-property-names-in-less-dynamic-properties-property-name-in).

Comment: It's weird, though. According to the thread you linked this isn't an issue as of version 1.6 - I'm using 1.7 and seeing the problem. how come?

Comment: Same here mate, I am finding it wierd too. I didn't expect this issue and that's why didn't mention in the original answer, but then I was double checking your sample in question and found this. It should be mostly because of the `@` in front (the example in the linked thread doesn't have it). I will let you know if I happen to find a reason.

Comment: Here's another silly workaround: define `@i: ~" ";` at the top, then: `@{i}@{left}: 10px;` results in `@LEFT@: 10px;` with an added space

Comment: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2168) about the weird behavior.

Comment: **update:** the issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2173)